# Reducing image collection separately for each image to make series?

Tags: google-earth-engine, image

I know how to reduce a collection to one image, or an image to a value in Google Earth Engine. But I can not find an easy way to reduce each image in a collection to a statistics and get a list of that. How it can be done?

As it is easy to get a list of a metadata property over a collection, I was thinking that maybe I can just add my statistics as a metadata to each image, but I couldn't find any way to add a property to the image. Also even if I can, then maybe I can not apply it over collection because the output is not a map.

Any help?

Comment: What statistics are you looking for - can you provide a (code) example of the calculation you perform for a single image?

Comment: I mean, I can define a region in an image and then calculate the minimum value of a desired band using `image.reduceRegion`. Also I can reduce the collection of images to an image consisting of minimum values for each pixel through all collection using `collection.reduce`. But I want to reduce each image in the collection separately and have the minimum of all of its pixels in a list.

Comment: I think what you want to do is to map the reducer function over the collection? https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_mapping

Comment: Oh yes you are right! I am new to GEE. Thank you very much.

Comment: You should mark this as answered.

Comment: @Noel Sorry but I can not find a way to mark this as answered! There are just two up and down arrows and a star at the right side of my question, and nothing else.